# Is the modus ponens is an axiom in formal logic?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

Modus Ponens is a rule of inference, which is not exactly an axiom. As far as I understand an axiom is a starting point for a proof, while a rule of inference is tools used to make conclusions out the axioms given. So doesnt that make rules of inference axioms themselves? Correct me if im wrong.

Comment: If you've done any programming, it might help to think of "rules of inference" as corresponding to the "syntax" of a program language, whereas "axioms" correspond to "standard library functions" provided by the language's runtime.

Answer (score 4):

> $(Q)$ : [Are] rules of inference axioms themselves?

*Rules of inference* formalize the "basic" inference steps, i.e. the "legal" moves from one or more sentences (asserted or assumed) : the *premises*, to a new one : the *conclusion*.

*Axioms* are sentences assumed to be true.

We can see :

- Stephen Cole Kleene, [Introduction to Metamathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=HZAjPwAACAAJ) (1952), page 80, for the discussion about *deductive rules* or *transformation rules*, and page 83 :

> Carnap [*The logical syntax of language*, 1934] brings [axioms and rules] under the common term "transformatiion rules", by considering the axioms as the result of transformation from zero premises.

Thus, we can say instead that axioms are "a sort of" rules ...